# ArcPy hangs during raster calculations but Raster Calculator tool works just fine

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm trying to perform raster calculations on a list of rasters using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro, but it just hangs. However, when I use the Raster Calculator tool it performs just fine.

Does this happening have something to do with my code?

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

eng = arcpy.ListRasters('ENG*')
species_abbr = "ENG"

b1b2_2060 = []
b1b2_2090 = []
a2_2060 = []
a2_2090 = []

for item in eng:
    if species_abbr in item and "2060" in item and "clipped" in item and ("B1" in item or "B2" in item):
        b1b2_2060.append(item)
    elif species_abbr in item and "2090" in item and "clipped" in item and ("B1" in item or "B2" in item):
        b1b2_2090.append(item)
    elif species_abbr in item and "2060" in item and "clipped" in item and "A2" in item:
        a2_2060.append(item)
    elif species_abbr in item and "2090" in item and "clipped" in item and "A2" in item:
        a2_2090.append(item)

if (len(b1b2_2060) == 3) and (len(b1b2_2090) == 3) and (len(a2_2060) == 3) and (len(a2_2090) == 3):
        outraster_1 = Raster(b1b2_2060[0]) + Raster(b1b2_2060[1]) + Raster(b1b2_2060[2])
        outraster_1.save(r"lynx_connectivity.gdb\{}".format(species_abbr + "_B1B2_2060_ADDED"))
        print("{} successfully added together".format(b1b2_2060))

        outraster_2 = Raster(b1b2_2090[0]) + Raster(b1b2_2090[1]) + Raster(b1b2_2090[2])
        outraster_2.save(r"lynx_connectivity.gdb\{}".format(species_abbr + "_B1B2_2090_ADDED"))
        print("{} successfully added together".format(b1b2_2090))

        outraster_3 = Raster(a2_2060[0]) + Raster(a2_2060[1]) + Raster(a2_2060[2])
        outraster_3.save(r"lynx_connectivity.gdb\{}".format(species_abbr + "_A2_2060_ADDED"))
        print("{} successfully added together".format(a2_2060))

        outraster_4 = Raster(a2_2090[0]) + Raster(a2_2090[1]) + Raster(a2_2090[2])
        outraster_4.save(r"lynx_connectivity.gdb\{}".format(species_abbr + "_A2_2090_ADDED"))
        print("{} successfully added together".format(a2_2090))
else:
    print('LENGTH ERROR')
```

Comment: Is this all happening inside same default workspace?

Comment: @FelixP it is all in the same default workspace and I'm using jupyter notebook inside ArcGIS pro.

Comment: At what point does it hang?

Comment: When you run standalone script, it's using environment extent from ArcCatalog. Does it match your rasters extents? If not ArcGIS will struggle to do rasters algebra.